# Web3 provider in Unity

Tags: web3js, metamask

I working with projects on the blockchain. Making web apps which communicating with smart contracts, giving tokens or etc.

For web apps, I need to get users wallet (Ethereum). I using these software/extensions: MetaMask, Portis, Fortmatic.

Now I making an app on Unity and I starting research of Web3 providers software for Unity.

MetaMask - is working only in PC browsers, working like an extension (Chrome). Portis - working on JavaScript (I using in React framework), they didn't support an opportunity to integrate that in Unity. Fortmatic - same like Portis.

Maybe you know someone, who solve the same problem or some software to do that. That would be great!

Comment: check https://blog.enjincoin.io/the-blockchain-sdk-by-enjin-is-live-on-the-unity-asset-store-a0b05f498b6e

Comment: "ivan on tech academy" will do soon a  Tutorial of unity with Blockchain

Comment: Man, I've seen Enjin but I'd want something  that integrates straight with Ether and now have to go through a middleman coin. Middleman coins mean yet another technical explanation to give users, which means fewer of them will take the action.

Did you ever find a good solution for this or did you just use Enjin or Loom?